# How to modify this VBA code for VB

Tags: vba, vb6

I am using this VBA code for covnvert textbox text to regular text. But its through errors on `shp.Type` and `sString = Left(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, _
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count - 1)`, while i am compiling in VB.

What should i change in the code for VB?

**This is VBA code:**

```
Sub ConvertTextBoxToText()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim oRngAnchor As Range
    Dim sString As String

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes

        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            ' copy text to string, without last paragraph mark
            sString = Left(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, _
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count - 1)

            If Len(sString) > 0 Then
                ' set the range to insert the text
                Set oRngAnchor = shp.Anchor.Paragraphs(1).Range
                ' insert the textbox text before the range object
                oRngAnchor.InsertBefore sString
            End If

            shp.Delete

        End If

    Next shp

    'Strip out beginning and ending textbox markers
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Textbox start << "
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        ' .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ">> Textbox end"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

**VB Code:?**

Could you please?

Comment: What is the error and where?

Comment: `shp.Type` and `sString = Left(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, _
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count - 1)`

Comment: The first step would be to properly indent your code. Honestly, is all your code completely left-aligned? How do you even read that mess?

Comment: Method or data member not found

Comment: What is the type of shape? A `Text Frame` or `Text box`? `Text box` is acontrol. `Text frame` is a shape. You should call proper properties of the object.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-translation service. Please make the translation yourself and ask if you need help about a specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB uses VBA as it's language. So no conversion needed. VB is an app object and forms package that hosts VBA, like Word is a Word Processor that hosts VBA.

In your code you don't connect to Word. In Word, some objects are made automatically available. Outside of Word you have to connect to them.

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls")
For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
    msgbox wsheet.name
    wsheet.printOut 
next
```

or

```
set xlapp = createobject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls"
'43 is 95/97 look up xlExcel9795 in object browser to see other options
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\User\Documents\Super.xls", 43
```

or

```
Set GetExcelApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
Msgbox GetExcelApp
```